# Ubuntu One for other Linux Distributions?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm using Mageia Linux on one of my computers and I would like to sync with my Ubuntu One account, is this possible?

Comment: This question is likely no longer useful, since Ubuntu One is discontinued.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is no lock-in. The Ubuntu One client is written in Python, so it should run well on any GNU/Linux distro. I don't know if it's been packaged for other distros though, but all dependencies should be easily resolvable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. You even can run Ubuntu One on your Android mobile (soon).